# Django: Правильно ли использовать dict в views.py

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте!
В нескольких туториалах встречал использование dict в views.py, например:

```
def home(request):
images_all = ImagesArticles.objects.all()
article_get = Articles.objects.filter(is_active=True)
image_get = images_all.filter(is_main=True)
articles = {}
count = 0
for i in article_get:
    articles[count] = {}
    articles[count]['title'] = i.article_title
    articles[count]['slug'] = i.article_slug
    articles[count]['text'] = i.article_text
    articles[count]['date'] = i.article_pup_date
    articles[count]['video'] = i.article_video
    for image in image_get:
        if image.image_articles_id == i.id:
            articles[count]['image'] = image.image_thumbnail
    count += 1

context = {
    'articles': articles,
}
return render(request, 'articles/home.html', context)
```

Потом в шаблоне

```
{% for key, value in articles %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: И что не устраивает?

Comment: Скорее смущает то, что кроме учебных проектов ни где не встречал, может плохо искал.

Comment: Это вполне нормально.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ!

Comment: Использование словарей допустимо, хорошо читаемы, но на практике их редко используют, мне в return удобнее прописать переменные. В данном случае целесообразность под вопросом у кода примера. Получили все изображения, получили статьи, связали каждую статью с изображением. Это если изображений до 100 тыс хорошо в памяти посчитать, а если их под миллион? Лучше с базой данных работать.

Comment: Переменную удобно передавать в шаблон только если в куэрисете не много объектов. Если у тебя там больше 1000 объектов то будет пипец как тормозить. Ведь для каждого объекта будет запрос в бд. А словарь будет в памяти и все будет значительно быстрее.